# Why is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {1/2 \choose k} = \sqrt{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

As the header states, I would like to know, why $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {1/2 \choose k} = \sqrt{2}$. I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} = 2^n$, so this seems naturally. The proof for the 2nd statement was done by induction, hence I do not have a clue how I could expand this proof.
Additionally I tried to take a look at the definition of ${n \choose k}$ if n is a complex number, but I do not think rewriting the sum in this way helps.

Any hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Type "binomial theorem" into the internet, keep looking until you find a proof. This is just the binomial theorem for $(1+1)^{1/2}$.

Comment: In order to prove such identity we need to know what is your *definition* of $\binom{1/2}{k}$. If one defines the generalized binomial coefficients through the coefficients of the Maclaurin series of $(1+x)^\alpha$ there is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fine points which are left out in other answers.

---

First of all the *general binomial theorem* says that if $x, n$ are real numbers with $|x|<1$ then $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom {n} {k} x^k\tag{1}$$ where the binomial coefficient $\binom{n} {k} $ is defined via $$\binom{n} {0}=1,\,\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots (n-k+1)}{k!}, \, k=1,2,\dots\tag{2}$$ When $n$ is a positive integer then the series at the right hand side of equation $(1) $ is a finite series as all terms with $k>n$ are zero and this case is the easier one to handle and routinely proved using induction. If $n$ is not a positive integer then the series in $(1)$ is an infinite series and the proof of binomial theorem for this case is conveniently left out in most introductory calculus texts.

The result can be proved [using Taylor's theorem](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part1.html) or [using the Cauchy formula for multiplication of infinite series](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part2.html). These proofs typically require the condition $|x|<1$ and with some more effort it can be proved that the result is true for $x=\pm 1$ also for certain values of $n$.

For the current problem $x=1$ and then it is known that the result holds for all $n>-1$ and thus for the question at hand we have $n=1/2$ and the desired sum is $(1+1)^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The Generalized Binomial Theorem was discovered by Isaac Newton. I dk his method but for $a,b\in \Bbb N$ and $|x|<1$ he may have computed the co-efficients of $(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom {a/b}{n}x^n)^b$ to be the same as those of $(1+x)^a$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try expanding the polynomials $p_n(x) = (1+x)^n$, where $n$ is an integer. Write out the Pascal triangle beside them. You can discover that the coefficient $c_{n,m}$ of $x^m$ is exactly $\left(\begin{align}m\\n\end{align}\right)$. Now try to generalize this to the case where $n=1/2$, and substitute $x=1$, you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of the generalized binomial theorem$$(a+b)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}b+\frac {n(n-1)}{2!}a^{n-2}b^2+\cdots$$
Where $n$ doesn’t necessarily have to be an integer. If $n$ *is* an integer, then the binomial theorem turns into the regular binomial theorem you probably learned in eigth grade. Now set $a=b=1$ and $n=1/2$.